# Show plot instead of save a PDF of it

Tags: r, sublimetext

I'm in the first steps of R programming. Using Sublime Text 3 for it. I'm trying to plot some data, with the following code:

```
cars <- c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)
windows()
plot(cars)
```

I was expecting to see the graph just after hit Ctrl+B but just now I've noted a PDF file was save with the graph.

Is it possible to see the graph instead of save the file?

Trying `dev.off()` I got:

```
Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device) 
Execution halted
```

And trying `getOption("device")` I got:

```
function (file = if (onefile) "Rplots.pdf" else "Rplot%03d.pdf", 
    width, height, onefile, family, title, fonts, version, paper, 
    encoding, bg, fg, pointsize, pagecentre, colormodel, useDingbats, 
    useKerning, fillOddEven, compress) 
{
    initPSandPDFfonts()
    new <- list()
    if (!missing(width)) 
        new$width <- width
    if (!missing(height)) 
        new$height <- height
    if (!missing(onefile)) 
        new$onefile <- onefile
    if (!missing(title)) 
        new$title <- title
    if (!missing(fonts)) 
        new$fonts <- fonts
    if (!missing(version)) 
        new$version <- version
    if (!missing(paper)) 
        new$paper <- paper
    if (!missing(encoding)) 
        new$encoding <- encoding
    if (!missing(bg)) 
        new$bg <- bg
    if (!missing(fg)) 
        new$fg <- fg
    if (!missing(pointsize)) 
        new$pointsize <- pointsize
    if (!missing(pagecentre)) 
        new$pagecentre <- pagecentre
    if (!missing(colormodel)) 
        new$colormodel <- colormodel
    if (!missing(useDingbats)) 
        new$useDingbats <- useDingbats
    if (!missing(useKerning)) 
        new$useKerning <- useKerning
    if (!missing(fillOddEven)) 
        new$fillOddEven <- fillOddEven
    if (!missing(compress)) 
        new$compress <- compress
    old <- check.options(new, name.opt = ".PDF.Options", envir = .PSenv)
    if (!missing(family) && (inherits(family, "Type1Font") || 
        inherits(family, "CIDFont"))) {
        enc <- family$encoding
        if (inherits(family, "Type1Font") && !is.null(enc) && 
            enc != "default" && (is.null(old$encoding) || old$encoding == 
            "default")) 
            old$encoding <- enc
        family <- family$metrics
    }
    if (is.null(old$encoding) || old$encoding == "default") 
        old$encoding <- guessEncoding()
    if (!missing(family)) {
        if (length(family) == 4L) {
            family <- c(family, "Symbol.afm")
        }
        else if (length(family) == 5L) {
        }
        else if (length(family) == 1L) {
            pf <- pdfFonts(family)[[1L]]
            if (is.null(pf)) 
                stop(gettextf("unknown family '%s'", family), 
                  domain = NA)
            matchFont(pf, old$encoding)
        }
        else stop("invalid 'family' argument")
        old$family <- family
    }
    version <- old$version
    versions <- c("1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", 
        "2.0")
    if (version %in% versions) 
        version <- as.integer(strsplit(version, "[.]")[[1L]])
    else stop("invalid PDF version")
    onefile <- old$onefile
    if (!checkIntFormat(file)) 
        stop(gettextf("invalid 'file' argument '%s'", file), 
            domain = NA)
    .External(C_PDF, file, old$paper, old$family, old$encoding, 
        old$bg, old$fg, old$width, old$height, old$pointsize, 
        onefile, old$pagecentre, old$title, old$fonts, version[1L], 
        version[2L], old$colormodel, old$useDingbats, old$useKerning, 
        old$fillOddEven, old$compress)
    invisible()
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000f0e4c80>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
```

Comment: ensure to close ll graphic devices using `dev.off()`

Comment: Why vote down the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using either the standalone R console or another programme such as RStudio, the default behaviour is to show the plot rather than save it as a pdf. Try using `dev.off()` to reset the graphics device.

Failing that, what happens if you call `getOption("device")`?

Comment: OK, I think you will need to open a new graphics device. Run `windows()` first, then call your plot.

Comment: See https://github.com/DataScienceSpecialization/courses/blob/master/04_ExploratoryAnalysis/GraphicsDevices/index.md for more details!

Comment: Now I see a blink. But the graph closes immediately. Why?

Comment: Does it close immediately after running `windows()` or only after you then run `plot(...)`?

Comment: Just noted it works from the R (win cmd) console, even without `windows()`. It might be something related to Sublime Build system, it closes immediately after i hit `Ctrl+B`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Afraid not - I'm not familiar with Sublime. Could try running `dev.new()` and see if that opens a new window which stays open? Failing that, I'm not fresh out of ideas.

Comment: If you're new to R and haven't tried it before, you could consider using RStudio instead of Sublime?